# Iterative binary search tree using enum and match

Tags: rust

I am a beginner, so bear with me.

Given the following enum definition for a BST.

```
enum Tree {
    Node(i64, Box<Tree>, Box<Tree>),
    Nil,
}
```

I want to implement `Tree::insert`. Here is what I have so far. (Get ready for spaghetti).

```
impl Tree {
    fn new() -> Tree {
        Nil
    }

    fn insert(self: &mut Tree, new_val: i64) -> Tree {
        let mut temp = self;
        loop {
            match *temp {
                Node(val, ref mut left, ref mut right) => /* go left is smaller, else go right*/,
                Nil => { break; },
            }
        }
        /* create new node and have the left or right pointer of the leaf point to it  */
        return *self;
    }
```

I understand how I would implement this with functional style, where I construct a new tree each call with the left and right subtree being the result of the recursive call to insert on the appropriate subtree. I also think I could implement this more easily with a struct. But I want to use this mix of styles.

Onto what is confusing me...

Conceptually, I want to have a reference to the root, and then continue mutating this reference to the left or right subtrees, as I would if I wrote this in C++. But because of borrowing semantics, I can't seem to navigate to the left and right subtree by making a copy of a reference. Additionally, rust doesn't seem to give me access to pointers to the same degree that C/C++ do, and I am generally confused as heck.

Any tips regarding what I need to do to make this piece of code work without outright giving up and moving to functional style or making a struct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read [Learning Rust with too many linked lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of the following?

```
fn insert(self: &mut Tree, new_val: i64) {
    let mut temp : &mut Tree = self;
    loop {
        temp = match temp {
            Tree::Node(val, ref mut left, ref mut right) => {
                if new_val<*val {
                    left.as_mut()
                } else {
                    right.as_mut()
                }
            },
            Tree::Nil => { break; },
        }
    }
    *temp = Tree::Node(new_val, Box::new(Tree::Nil), Box::new(Tree::Nil))
}
```